# Line integral - should I parametrize the square?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, differential-forms

I have the following $1-\text{form}$ defined: $$\omega = \displaystyle\frac{2xy}{(1-x^2)^2+y^2}\mathrm{dx}+\displaystyle\frac{1-x^2}{(1-x^2)^2+y^2}\mathrm{dy}$$ I'd like to find $\displaystyle\oint_{\gamma}\omega$ where $\gamma$ is the square defined by the points $(2,-1),(2,1),(0,1),(0,-1)$ counter clockwise.

Since the square is a closed path, if $\omega$ is exact then $\displaystyle\oint_\gamma \omega =0$, right?

This is something I have proved using $$\int\omega=y\int\frac{2x}{(1-x^2)^2}+y^2 dx  \\ \text{change variables: }u= (1-x^2)\implies du=-2x \\ =-y\int \frac{1}{(u/y)^2+1}du \\ \text{2nd change of variables: } z=u/y \implies dz=du/y \\ =-\int \frac{1}{z^2+1}dz = - \arctan(z)\\=-\arctan\left(\frac{1-x^2}{y}\right) + C(y)$$
And it seems to be enough if I set $C(y)=0$ since

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left(-\arctan\frac{1-x^2}{y}\right)=-\frac{1}{\frac{(1-x^2)^2}{y^2}+1}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{1-x^2}{y}\right) \\ =-\frac{y^2}{(1-x^2)^2+y^2}\left(-\frac{1-x^2}{y^2}\right) = \frac{1-x^2}{(1-x^2)^2+y^2}$$

Is this enough to show that $\displaystyle\oint_\gamma \omega =0$ ?

Comment: Do you mind stating the theorem you're using to conclude the integral is $0$?

Comment: @GitGud : If $\omega \in \Omega^1(U)$ (set of 1-forms in $U$) the following ones are equivalent: (1) $\int_\gamma \omega$  is independent of the path $\gamma$ in $U$, (2) $\oint_\gamma \omega =0$ for very closed path $\gamma$, (3) $\omega$ is exact.

Comment: OK, what assumptions are made about $U$?

Comment: The problem doesn't make it explicit, but it seems by the context that $\omega$ is exact in $\mathbb{R}^2 -U$ with $U=\{(x,y):|x|>1, y=0\}$, so looking back to the problem looks like I didn't prove $\omega$ is exact in the set I want to calculate $\oint \omega$. Maybe a better choice would be just parametrize the square?, I'll update my question briefly.

Comment: As far as I know you need that the vector field is $C^1$ in a simply connected set. But I don't know if what I learned was a weaker simplified version or if it holds even if the domain isn't simply connected.

Comment: Come to think about it, I think you do need a simply connected set. So you should parametrize the square.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of Green's theorem? It's quite simple to solve if you use Green's theorem.